# Emacs: Calling cua-mode cua-set-rectangle-mark from within custom function

Tags: emacs, cua-mode, cua

Currently I use cua-mode for its column/rectangle facilities like so (I don't used it for copy/pasting):

```
M-x cua-mode ; Enable cua-mode
<C-return>   ; Call cua-set-rectangle-mark
```

Then when I'm done with my rectangle:

```
C-g          ; Call cua-cancel
```

The bindings for CUA mode clash with other mode bindings (e.g. in org mode) so I sometimes find myself having to turn cua-mode on/off. I only ever use it for its rectangles - so I would like to solve this nuisance by doing two thing:

1) Bind a key (say f6) to a function which enables cua-mode if it is not already enabled and calls cua-set-rectangle-mark so I can create my rectangle.

2) Override C-g whilst cua-mode is active so that when pressed not only does it exit any rectangle but it also exits cua-mode.

So then my workflow would be:

```
<f6> ; Enter cua-mode and call cua-set-rectangle-mark
C-g  ; Call cua-cancel and disable cua-mode
```

That way I would not need constantly toggle cua-mode on/off when there are clashes.

For part 1 I've come up with:

```
(defun cua-activate-plus-set-rectangle-mark()
 (interactive)
 (cua-set-rectangle-mark))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'cua-activate-plus-set-rectangle-mark)
```

Pressing f6 works when cua-mode is already enabled but does not when cua-mode is not enabled. If I change it to be like so:

```
(defun cua-activate-plus-set-rectangle-mark()
 (interactive)
 (cua-mode)
 (cua-set-rectangle-mark))
```

then it doesn't work at all regardless of whether I started with cua-mode enabled or not.

For part 2 I have:

```
(defun cua-mode-off()
 "Cancels any open active region/rectangle and turns CUA mode off"
 (interactive)
 (cua-cancel)
 (setq cua-mode nil))
```

The function does exactly what I want it to but I do not know how to bind it to C-g when cua-mode is enabled.

So my questions:

1) How can I write the function to enter cua-mode and call cua-set-rectangle-mark so it works as expected?

2) How can I override C-g only whilst cua-mode is active to call my custom function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the behavior you're looking for already exists.  Take a look at `cua-rectangle-mark-mode`.  From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html):

> CUA mode provides enhanced rectangle support with visible rectangle
>   highlighting. Use `C-RET` to start a rectangle, extend it using the
>   movement commands, and cut or copy it using `C-x` or `C-c`. `RET` moves the
>   cursor to the next (clockwise) corner of the rectangle, so you can
>   easily expand it in any direction. Normal text you type is inserted to
>   the left or right of each line in the rectangle (on the same side as
>   the cursor).
>
> You can use this rectangle support without activating CUA by calling
>   the `cua-rectangle-mark-mode` command. But see also the standard
>   `rectangle-mark-mode`. See [Rectangles](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html#Rectangles).